# MySQL Query Profiling for Indexes

Tags: mysql

Is there a way which I can have MySQL record its queries and their Explain so that I can figure out how to index the expensive stuff? I'm new to this stuff. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try looking at maatkit. Particularly mk-query-digest. http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-query-digest.html

Comment: There is also `pt-query-digest`. +1 nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

First use [log-queries-not-using-indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-queries-not-using-indexes.) Then use [explain](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) on them to see possible indexes